# Unable to get data from model for rendering in Handlebars template

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I'm attempting to use Handlebars templates with Backbone w/ Marionette.  Maybe I'm biting off more frameworks than I can chew right now but if I can work through this last issue then I will have all the pieces worked out.

So what I have right now is  Marionette Layout being rendered with a Handlebars template.  The static code in the template is rendering so I am assuming that at least the basic wiring is correct.  I added some debug code to the success callback of my model's fetch call, like this:

```
success: function(model, response, options) {
    $.log(response);
}
```

What I get for the response is something like this (data sanitized but you get the idea):

```
{
    "adminLoginId": 0,
    "deviceHashAVInfos": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ],
    "orgId": 0,
    "timeTaken": 39,
    "numHits": 1,
    "message": "success",
    "success": true
}
```

So, it seems to be getting data back from the service. But for the life of me, I can't seem to get the syntax correct to read the data.  Just trying to access the orgId, for example, I've tried: `{{orgId}},{{this.orgId}},{{data.orgId}},{{response.orgId}},{{attributes.orgId}}`.  I've even tried to set the orgId as a default value in the model.

Comment: What is the code for the render method of your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a Marionette layout to display a model (it's used to display views in regions). Instead, try using an item view and pass the model as an arugment, like you can see here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/show/show_controller.js#L14

You can learn more about using basic views to display models here: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf

Comment: Thanks.  I did mean to organize the page that way but lost track of it.  Unortunately, I still can't seem to get the data.  I'll update my question to reflect the new refactoring.

Comment: Ok, forget it.  In the course of updating my question details.  I found the problem. A really stupid problem of the "missing comma" variety.  When I created my view instance, I forgot to specify the model! *Sigh* I knew it would end up being something stupid like that but I have so many new things in my head to keep track of.  Thanks a lot for your help.